# How to make a vertically center of viewport?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I explain my problem:

I have created an overlay, there is a gallery of thumbnail images and clicking on a picture, it will appear in a box with the image clicked to larger (the size fit the width of the window). This box is perfectly aligned horizontally and alignment remains even if you resize the window.

The problem is that I want a vertical alignment of the box. Aligned in the viewport, because I wish it was immediately visible. But I do not want during the scroll, the box does not move together with the page. (therefore be excluded **display: fixed**)

Now the box is so:

```
#box {
 padding: 0 5px 10px;
 background-color:#a0a0a0;
 margin: 5px 5px 15px 5px;
 display:none;
 z-index:+300;
 position:absolute;
 left:50%;
 top:20%;
 border-radius: 10px;
}
```

The div **#box** before that image is clicked, has **display:none**.
So the alignment in the viewport would only during the appearance of the box. When he moves the page (scroll) alignment does not matter.

**This is jsfiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/tvafw5Ls/13/

If is possible to do this only with CSS3 is better, but also solution with js is ok.

I hope that can you help me!
Thanks a lot!

Comment: So if I am reading correctly, you'd like the new image `#box` to be in the center of the viewport when clicked, but you want this new image to move with the page when you scroll?

Comment: Actually, I think he wants the Lightbox to be centered when clicked but then on scroll, it will stay in its initial position. I think he is having an issue of the lightbox being off the page when it is first clicked

Comment: I will say, the JS you are using could be cleaned up immensely. I am going to submit and answer but you will need to do the heavy lifting of cleaning up your code.

Comment: @rockmandew, Yup, we're saying the same thing :)

Comment: when the image is clicked, the box must to be in the center of viewport. Than if i scroll, i scroll all page (also the box)   @rockmandew yes you are right, in this moment i must to finish my code, when i will finish i will clean the code :) but if you want help me, i thank you

Comment: @User3162975 - I do want to help you and I have helped you below - my answer is a solution, I think you didn't think it worked because there was no scroll bar for you to scroll/test the solution. Please test again with the new Fiddle provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, here is your JsFiddle updated with the viewport centering - I adjusted this part of your code to look like so:

```
if (widthimage < i2.width) {
        $('#box').css('left', '50%');
        $('#box').css('top', '50%');
        $('#box').css('transform', 'translate(-50%,-50%)');
        $('#box').css('-webkit-transform', 'translate(-50%,-50%)');
        $("#immagine img:last-child").css('width', '100%');
    } else {
        $('#box').css('left', '50%');
        $('#box').css('top', '50%');
        $("#immagine img:last-child").css('width', '');
        $('#box').css('transform', 'translate(-50%,-50%)');
        $('#box').css('-webkit-transform', 'translate(-50%,-50%)');
    }


    $(window).resize(function () {
        $('#box').css('left', '0%');
        $("#immagine img:last-child").css('width', '100%');
        var widthimage = $("#immagine img:last-child").width();
        if (widthimage < i2.width) {
            $('#box').css('left', '50%');
            $('#box').css('top', '50%');
            $('#box').css('transform', 'translate(-50%,-50%)');
            $('#box').css('-webkit-transform', 'translate(-50%,-50%)');
            $("#immagine img:last-child").css('width', '100%');

        } else {
            $('#box').css('left', '50%');
            $('#box').css('top', '50%');
            $("#immagine img:last-child").css('width', '');
            $('#box').css('transform', 'translate(-50%,-50%)');
            $('#box').css('-webkit-transform', 'translate(-50%,-50%)');

        }

    });
```

What this is doing, is a nifty css trick that looks like this:

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
-moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

This will vertically and horizontally center anything in CSS.

Here is the JsFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/rockmandew/tvafw5Ls/17/

I will edit my answer to include how to make the lightbox stay fixed when scroll (if I understand your question correctly, you want the lightbox to stay in a fixed position if the user scrolls, but for it to center if the window/viewport is resized.)

** I lied, my current solution will make the lightbox stay in the initial position when scrolling - if you wanted it to follow the page on scroll you would add this to your code:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $( '#box' ).css('position', 'fixed');
});
```

** UPDATE ** I have updated my code to include lorem ipsum at the bottom to provide a scroll - test this link, if "it doesn't work" then your question is wrong. https://jsfiddle.net/rockmandew/tvafw5Ls/18/

Comment: I'm just going to note - I don't know why you would want to make the lightbox "fixed" on scrolling because you still have the overlay covering the entire page so the user wouldn't be able to really view the content anyways, but I'll provide a solution anyways.

Comment: exactly...  Not sure why either, but that's the ask.

Comment: How doesn't this work @user3162975 - I tested it to your exact details in your comment on ntgCleaner - Its doing exactly as you asked.

Answer (score 0):

Using your JS, I've come up with [This Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1eo8enL4/)

What I've done is changed your initial `#box` css to this:

```
#box {
    width:90%;
    max-width:775px;
    padding: 0 5px 10px;
    background-color:#a0a0a0;
    margin: 5px 5px 15px 5px;
    display:none;
    z-index:+300;
    position:fixed;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    border-radius: 10px;
}
#box #immagine img {
    width:100%;
}
```

Notice how I've changed the box to initially have the `fixed` position.  Then I've placed it in the dead center of the window using translate-negative-position.  I've also given the box a width and max-width so your js doesn't need to handle that.

After that, I've done a few things to your JS.  I removed the CSS you've given the box with the translate3d, then I've found the initial position of the fixed box, changed the position to `absolute` and given the height of the box position.

```
if (widthimage < i2.width) {
    //Took off the translates from here
    $('#box').css('left', '0%');
    $("#immagine img:last-child").css('width', '100%');
} else {
    //and here
    $('#box').css('left', '50%');
    $("#immagine img:last-child").css('width', '');
}

//Added this to the mix to make the box position absolute again
var imgOffsetTop = $('#box').position().top;
var boxHeight = $('#box').outerHeight();
$('#box').css({
    "position":"absolute",
    "top":(imgOffsetTop+(boxHeight/2))+"px"
});
```

**UPDATE**
I've turned the fixed-to-absolute solution into a function and have made it run on load and window resize.  I've also edited a bit more of your CSS, making your `#box` have a max-width and width.  Take a look at the fiddle for the example.

Comment: Your solution doesn't address the issue on resize - FOR EVERYONE ELSE, this answer doesn't require a downvote because of that - the question isn't exactly clear so ultimately, this answer does provide a solution - I just can't tell if the person asking the question is expecting more :p

Comment: @rockmandew Thanks for the heads up, I didn't read into him needing it on resize.

Comment: why you say that the question is not exact ?: When I click the image, #box must be aligned vertically in the viewport. But the position does not have to be fixed because I want to scroll all. But if I shake the box must remain in the position where it was when it appeared. I think it is more difficult to explain than to do. Imagine if you visit the page from the phone ... I do not want that you do not immediately see the box.

Comment: @ntgCleaner there a lot of issues... doesn't work, but thanks

Comment: @user3162975, Ok. Sorry, I must not be understanding properly.  The way I read it is: When the user clicks on an image, the image will appear in the center of the screen.  Then you also want the user to be able to scroll the page up and down while the image moves with the screen.  If this is correct, then I'm not sure what's wrong with my code.

Comment: @ntgCleaner When scroll the box must remain in the position where it appeared. Let me give an example: the height of the viewport is 400 px, the box measuring 200px, appear in the center then to 200px from the bottom. (for me to understand, let them also ends the content of the page, then the box appears in the center of the viewport, or 200 px from the end). If I scroll the page, the box will remain at 200px from the bottom of the page. Maybe it would be better to have a fixed position of the box, scroll the page unless the box so that will remain at the center of the viewport?

Comment: @user3162975 - Alright, this question has a solution; please look at my answer, just dont include the $(window).scroll() function - that is exactly what you asked for and its using your code.

Answer (score 0):

Pure CSS way, simulating a table and a cell, works nice in every modern browser. To just give you the base idea. http://jsfiddle.net/q8bevnL2/

```
<style>
#box{
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:black;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    display:table;
}

#content{   
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
</style>

<div id="box">
    <div id="content">My stuff</div>   
</div>
```

Comment: Please try to write proper code you are now mixing CSS with HTML that's not good..! :D -1 for that..!

Comment: Holy moly, you are very unforgiving :) Please comment every single post i've made.

Comment: Sorry,buddy just trying to keep the level professional..! :D You know ..! We can help each other by showing their weaknesses right??? or we can help each other positively that's everyone choice..!